# Categorize range of numeric column in R Using Revalue

Tags: r, mapping

I am trying to revalue the column score in my dataset. After I check the Min, 1st Qua, 3rd Quad and Max. I try to Label specific range as following code

```
data2019$Score <-revalue(data2019$Score,c
("(2.853,4.553]" = "Not Happy", "(4.553,6.187]" = "Happy", "(6.187,7.769]" = "Flourishing"))
```

I keep getting error that x is not a factor or a character vector.
Please be advised on this issue

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). You can try `dplyr::recode` instead.

Comment: @RonakShah  Since I have Score column with the smallest value is 2.853 to the largest value of 7.769. I divide into 3 different range and assign each range from low medium and high. in my case as Not Happy, Happy and Flourishing. I
"(2.853,4.553]" = "Not Happy"
"(4.553,6.187]" = "Happy"
"(6.187,7.769]" = "Flourishing"

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cut` with `labels` instead.

```
data2019$Group <- cut(data2019$Score, 3, 
                      labels = c("Not Happy", "Happy", "Flourishing"))
```

Comment: then I just asign interval for those labels?

Comment: Yes or you can get the intervals with `data2019$Interval <- cut(data2019$Score, 3)`